# what's the role of Em.Controller in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, controller, ember.js

i'm studying ember.js by myself.

and i want to know exact role of Em.Controller.

when i make basic ember app, the only time i use Em.Controller is

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend();
```

but i don't know why it should be Em.Controller instead of Em.ArrayController or Em.ObjectController.

i know that ArrayController or ObjectController are used for dealing with model.

so i understand that i have to use ArrayController or ObjectController when i deal with Models.

but what about Em.Controller?

it exists only for an App's ApplicationController?

and it seems Em.ArrayController and Em.ObjectController aren't inherited from Em.Controller

then what is the relationship between them?

i'm soooo confused....

Comment: Read up on Controllers here: http://www.itsgotwhatplantscrave.com/2009/07/30/root-controller-paradigm/. It really helped me understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Ember.Controller` is the simplier controller class. As you can see [in the Ember.Controller source code](http://goo.gl/7NUqD), it's just an object with a target (usually the router), and a store, and inherit `Ember.ControllerMixin`.
- `Ember.ObjectController` is an ObjectProxy, as you can see [in the ObjectController source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/83542a629c214f1a9e89dcf8b9388e48ae2ba4e8/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/object_controller.js#L23): when its content is set, all getters/setters are delegated to its content. So the ObjectController is used for manipulating one item.
- `Ember.ArrayController` acts like the ObjectController: its a proxy, but for an Array, as you can see [in the ArrayController source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/83542a629c214f1a9e89dcf8b9388e48ae2ba4e8/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/array_controller.js#L57). So the ArrayController is used for manipulating an array of items.
- `Ember.ControllerMixin` just has few methods for handling view `{{outlets}}`, as you again can see [in the Ember.ControllerMixin source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/83542a629c214f1a9e89dcf8b9388e48ae2ba4e8/packages/ember-views/lib/system/controller.js#L17) (note that the code here reopens the ControllerMixin)

And you've right, `Ember.ArrayController` and `Ember.ObjectController` aren't inherited from `Ember.Controller`, but they all extend the `Ember.ControllerMixin` described above.

I suggest you to read [Advice on & Instruction in the Use Of Ember.js by Trek](http://trek.github.com/), this article is not especially about controllers, but you'll learn a lot of thing, and understand how they work (outlets, for example).

Comment: I will read all these source codes, then I think I can get the point. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: you could accept the answer if you think it respond to your question :)